# Php Calculating two functions

Tags: php, function, variables

I am writing a program in which I want to plus two functions together and in the end I want to calculate the total. if anyone can help with this it will be appreciated.

```
    const PRICE_OF_Big_Mac = 2.50;
    public $Big_Mac = 0;
    public function calculate_dinein_price(){
    $dine = 0.00;
    $dine += $this->Big_Mac * self::PRICE_OF_Big_Mac;

    return $dine;
}
public function calculate_dinein_total(){
    $total_dine = 0.00;
    $total_dine = $total_dine + $dine;

    return $total_dine;
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking, though I'd suggest you start by reading the php.net documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt yeah you are right I realised after reading the question actually I checked out the module but there is nothing which could answer this anyway the first function of calculate_dinein_price calculates the price of dinein the in the second function I want to use the previous function price and want to get the total for dine in price.

Comment: Can you pleae post the full code? The error message seems very strange in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `$dine` in your second function because it's nowhere defined. The `$dine` from your first function is only a **local** variable.

I would suggest this solution which uses the fact that `calculate_dinein_price()` also returns the value of `$dine`:

```
public function calculate_dinein_total(){
    $total_dine = 0.00;
    $total_dine = $total_dine + $this->calculate_dinein_price();

    return $total_dine;
}
```

Comment: when use your code it says:Fatal error: Call to undefined method ArrayObject::calculate_dinein_total() in mac.php on line 51

Comment: @rocker789 Are your methods in the same class?

Comment: @rocker789 Did you define the methods in the same class declaration?

Comment: yes I did should share it?

Comment: @rocker789 That would be helpful. Please post the code in your question.

Comment: I have written the code.

Comment: @rocker789 Yeah, but not the full code. Your posted code works fine for me: http://ideone.com/AMJ6uh